# Array not initialized properly in STM32Cube IDE

Tags: stm32, c++, stm32cubeide

I have a function conv 2D , that takes in 4D and 1D vectors as inputs (inputs, weights,outputs and biases) along with size parameters which are int (filter height, width etc). The function directly modifies the output array after performing convolution. This function works well in my C++ compiler, but when I tried it on STM32Cube IDE, I got incorrect results. Whenever I tried accessing the elements of the output array, It was always 0.

I then tried out this piece of code (and didn't call the function) :

```
vector<vector<vector<vector<float>>>> output_1(1, vector<vector<vector<float>>>(23, vector<vector<float>>(249, vector<float>(4, 6.0))));

int s1 = output_1.size();

int v1 = output_1[0][0][0][0];
```

output_1 is a `(1,23,249,4)` array initialized with all 6s. However, in the live expression counter, `s1` and `v1` are both giving 0. **Clearly the vector isn't initialized properly**. What is the problem here? Is there an alternative way to initialize the output vector?

I'm using the STM32H747I-DISCO board.

Edit: I have another 4d vector whose size and first value is being displayed properly. (above these 3 lines). when I move that to below these 3 lines, s1 and v1 are now correctly displayed as 1 and 6, but now I get 0,0 for the other vector.

Comment: Well, what does the whole code looks like if someone wants to test this? Also, this is not an issue in the IDE, but in the GCC compiler it uses under the hood. Also, do you know if this requires some support from the compiler? If the variable is global, don't you need support for global constructors, and do you know if compiler supports global constructors?

Comment: For now I'm just executing these 3 lines of code before the main function in main.cpp of my project. I have no idea about compiler support though. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Try setting your optmization options to -O0 .. this will disable optimization and allow you to view your variables. Chances are those variables are being optimized away. Also, what do you mean by "before the main function"? We need to see more code, especially the context.

Comment: My optimization is indeed O0.

Comment: @Justme I have edited the question. Ignore my earlier remark that I was executing just 3 lines of code.